# How to fix the issue with Deeplinking from facebook post to the app or webpage?

Tags: javascript, facebook, deep-linking

I am creating a deeplinking to app. when i have posted a link from website to Facebook. when i click on the link from Facebook, it will open if targeted app is installed otherwise showing error message a 'page could not load'. But it should open webpage if app not installed. Can any one help me on this

```html
<script>
    (function() {
    var app = {
        launchApp: function() {
            window.location.replace("appname://");
            this.timer = setTimeout(this.openWebApp, 1000);
        },

        openWebApp: function() {
            window.location.replace("'www.domain.com'");
        }
    };
    app.launchApp();
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe use a full, absolute URL then, instead of a relative URL …?

Comment: Are you using the FB native app or FB from the browser?
What is your platform (Android\iOS)?

Comment: @DrorDavidi, i am testing with Fb android app

Comment: Your approach seems fine - did you try the first comment that suggested to use an absolute URL?

Comment: .@04FS   , @DrorDavidi,  i tried with that too.. but not working .

Answer (score 0):

Could not post this as comment, trying here:

long shot but maybe you can try - Why do you add single quotes to your redirect?

I see: `window.location.replace("'www.xyz.com'");`

Maybe try: `window.location.replace("http://...");`